# How to run a program automatically on printing

Tags: java, printing, configuration, ubuntu-13.10

Good Morning,
I developed a simple application that show me my printers ink levels on a java gui.
[image: my Gui]

I'd like to run this program automatically every time that Ubuntu send to the printer print command. Can anybody help me?

Comment: off-topic, should migrate to http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you can make users to use shortcuts, you can set your thread to be activated if "some key" is pressed.
https://java.net/projects/jna/sources/svn/content/trunk/jnalib/contrib/w32keyhook/KeyHook.java

Once i used to code a keylogger for windows, and used this one. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: mmm, i'd like to attach my software directly on print spooler if is possible... Otherwise your solution is not bad.